# Endowment of an agent

Tags: welfare-economics, walrasian, resource-allocation

I was going through the Shapley-Folkman-Starr Lemma (https://simons.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/docs/3605/simons2.pdf) and I came across the term "endowment" of an agent.

My assumption is that it represents a (sub)set of the agent's preferred bundles. Could someone please clarify this term?

Comment: That's what the agent owns before trading.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker post answers as answers please

Comment: @1muflon1 I doubt this question will ever be asked again. Feel free to post it though.